# JMeter use beanshell variable in HTTP Request

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I'm an absolute rookie here (JAVA i mean), spent hours looking for a solution, now i just want to shoot myself.
I want to create a string in the beanshell assertion which is placed right above the HTTP Request.

- In the beanshell i wrote:

  ```
  String docid="abcd";
  ```

  (in actuality i wish to concatenate a string with some variables)
- In HTTP Request, send parameters i add `${docid}`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In [BeanShell Assertion description section](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) you can find the following:

```
 vars -  JMeterVariables  - e.g. vars.get("VAR1"); vars.put("VAR2","value"); vars.putObject("OBJ1",new Object()); 
 props - JMeterProperties (class java.util.Properties) - e.g. props.get("START.HMS"); props.put("PROP1","1234");
```

So to set jmeter variable in beanshell code (BeanShell Assertion sampler in your case) use the following:

```
String docid = "abcd";
vars.put("docid",docid);
```

or simply

```
vars.put("docid","abcd");
```

and then you can refer it as ${docid}, as you've done in your HTTP Request.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help!! If i'm not asking too much how will i be able to concatenate a variable in the beanshell assertion only. my objective is actually to run a loop and keep concatenating the string. I was planning to run this sampler in a loop controller and concatenate the variable to itself with little modifications with each loop run

Comment: Ignore the above comment, i managed to do concatenation and also looping, but somehow i am not able to pass the value from one beanshell sampler to another. i tried the vars.get("varname") but its not working. it only works for http request type variables.

Comment: Hm. Try use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) at least to track problem variable between beanshell samplers. As well you can also use props.get/.put in the same manner - maybe this will work better.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know Java well, you can use any of BSF or JSR223 Test elements and then select Javascript language as scripting language

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass value from one bean shell sampler to another, you should use variables.

```
vars.put("a", "something")
```

In other sampler, you should have something like:

```
String otherSampler = vars.get("a")
```

About debugging Shell Samplers - It is not so easy. I suggest to use SampleResult object. How to use it, you can see here [Debugging Bean Shell Sampler](http://jmeter-performance-functional-testing.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-use-java-code-in-jmeter.html)