# Jmeter use data from JDBC Request in HTTP Request

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, httprequest

I need to use data from RDBC request in HTTP request. Before ask this question I read these topics:

- [How to use responses from a Jmeter JDBC Request in a HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019598/how-to-use-responses-from-a-jmeter-jdbc-request-in-a-http-request)
- [JMeter use beanshell variable in HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671097/jmeter-use-beanshell-variable-in-http-request)
- [JMeter get jdbc request data and send each with http post request in a spring service how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741264/jmeter-get-jdbc-request-data-and-send-each-with-http-post-request-in-a-spring-se)

but I still don't know how to do this.

Test Structure:

```
JDBC Connection Configuration
JDBC Request
ForEach Controller
    BeanShell Sampler
    HTTP Request
```

My steps:

1. Created **JDBC Request** that return data in 2 columns and added variable names (years, elements).
2. Next I use **ForEach Controller** to read data from rows. **Input variable prefix: years, elements** and **Output variable name: years1, elements1**;
3. parse data from variables with **BeanShell Sampler**:

   ```
   String yearsRange = vars.get("years1"); String year =
   yearsRange.split("-")[1];

   String ElementsStr = vars.get("elements1"); String element =
   ElementsStr.split(" ")[1];

   vars.put("year", year);
   vars.put("element", element);
   ```
4. And now I create HTTP Request with parameters:

   ```
   year ${year};
   element ${element};
   ```

   I know that problem is with **ForEach Controller** (if I set one variable, all works fine) but I don't have any idea how to make it work with 2 or more variables.

Please give me advice what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) config element or [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function to iterate 2nd variable like:

[image: Foreach Controller]

[image: View Results Tree]

And I don't think you need Beanshell Sampler as JDBC Request returns resulting variables in the form which ForEach Controller can consume, like:

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
anothervar_1=baz
anothervar_2=somethingelse
```

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need.